# Как QT определяет размер QAction с иконкой?

Tags: c++, qt

Добрый день :)

Есть `QToolBar` и `QAction` для которого установлена иконка, но не установлен текст. Размер используемой иконки мне известен ( 16 или 32 ) в зависимости от разрешения экрана. Созданный `QAction` добавляется в `QToolBar` с помощью метода `addAction`. Создается кнопка с иконкой. Мне надо сделать кнопки такого-же размера. Как QT определяет размер получившейся кнопки?

На данный момент я думаю что это iconSize + отступ от иконки. Как получить значение отступа? Буду рад любым соображениям на эту тему :)

**Обновление**

Получается что бы создать кнопку такого-же размера как и на тулбаре я должен добавить к размеру контента 2 размера `ButtonMargin`(вверх и вниз)?

```
int buttonMargin = QApplication::style()->pixelMetric( QStyle::PM_ButtonMargin );
int buttonSize = ButtonMargin * 2 + contentSize;
```

Я правильно понял?

Судя по тому, что я проверил `QApplication::style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_ButtonMargin);` возвращает 6 на всех платформах :(
Хотя на винде Padding всего лишь 1 пиксель, соответственно Margin должен быть 3

Answer (score 1):

Для каждого QAction, создается свой QToolButton (на каждом из bar-ов в который он включен).  Можно получить его, и далее поправить все, что угодно..

```
QToolBar bar;
dynamic_cast<QToolButton*>( bar.widgetForAction(action) )->  ...
```

Отступы между картинкой и границами кнопки определяются по алгоритму описанному здесь: http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.5.0/stylesheet-customizing.html#box-model

Если нужно что-то поменять для всех кнопок на панели, проще всего это сделать с помощью qss:

```
bar.setStyleSheet(
            " QToolBar { spacing: 0px; } "
            " QToolButton { border: 0px; } "
            );
```

Спросить размер элемента с учетом текущих модификаций из qss, можно так:

```
QToolButton tmpToolButton; // Этот элемент не показывается. Но если вместо него задать null, ответ будет неправильный (без учета qss).
QSize result=QApplication::style()->sizeFromContents( QStyle::CT_ToolButton, 0, bar.iconSize(), &tmpToolButton );
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за наводку. Обновил вопрос.